# Applet error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: junit, applet

I created an applet which runs a junit test.
When I run the applet from Eclipse everythings works fine.
When I try to embed it in HTML, I get the UI correctly but when I click OK to start executing the test I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/notification/RunListener
    at lefty.GuiContainer$1.actionPerformed(GuiContainer.java:32)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 36 more
```

I have included all my classes plus all externan jar files in one .jar and i use it when i call the applet from the HTML. 
My HTML is as simple as it gets:

```
   <html>
   <title> Performance App </title>
   <body>
   <h2> Applet... </h2>
   <applet code=lefty.AppletSetup.class width="200" height="200"       archive="performanceApp.jar">
   </applet>
   </body>
   </htmL>
```

Also i have to mention that one of my class extends RunListener but I have included the junit.jar in my classpath and final jar.

Answer (score 1):

> Also i have to mention that one of my class extends RunListener but I
>   have included the junit.jar in my classpath and final jar.

Some points as

- A) How did you included external jars to your project jar?
- B) classpath - you mean a util running?
- C)

  > Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  >   org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener this line says the class is really missing so is it in project jar ?

And I suppose you shouldn't deploy applet with unit test code; Just because all unit tests are for IDE applet emulating running; So try to deploy it without junit

Good luck